# Beginner Python web scraping issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and would really appreciate some help!
I want to make a search and return its results, but it comes back with a run-time error.
My current code looks like this:

```
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('Please enter your first name')
firstName = input()
print('Please enter your surname')
secondName = input()
query = firstName + ' ' + secondName
print('Please enter language ex:[en,fr,ar,jp,cn...]: ')
lang = input()

# requests
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?hl={}&q;={}&start;=3i#=10&ie;=UTF-8'.format(lang, query)
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
# url source
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

# BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
# find all divs that contain search result
search_div = soup.find_all(class_='rc')
for result in search_div:
    # loop result list
    #geting h3
    print('Title: %s'%result.h3.string)
    print('\n')
    #geting a.href
    print('Url: %s'%result.a.get('href'))
    print('\n')
    # description
    print('Description: %s'%result.find(class_='st').text)
    print('\n###############\n')
```

Yet I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/axy/PycharmProjects/Name_Search/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
  File "/Users/axy/PycharmProjects/Name_Search/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 242, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am a beginner at this and would really appreciate a bit of guidance.
I was also hoping that someone could explain what this line means:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: to install lxml parser - `pip installl lxml`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install lxml.

Just pip install lxml and it should work

Comment: Thanks! I've done this and the error is gone but the list of the urls found from the search is not showing. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Looks like the page is rendered using javascript, BS4 can render jaavascript, so you'll have to use a library like Selenium, 

Google has implemented anti crawling messures, so I'm quite sure you'll have a bad time crawling them

Answer (score 0):

in this line `soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')` you are using `lxml` parser without installing it.

run `pip install lxml` it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've done this and the error is gone but the list of the urls found from the search is not showing. Do you know why this is?